# What is causing this discrepancy between the metric displayed at Catboost.select_features's plot and the actual predictions of the fitted final model?

Tags: python, python-3.x, machine-learning, feature-selection, catboost

I'm performing feature selection with Catbost. This the training code:

```
# Parameter grid
params = {
            'auto_class_weights': 'Balanced',
            'boosting_type': 'Ordered',
            'thread_count': -1,
            'random_seed': 24,
            'loss_function': 'MultiClass',
            'eval_metric': 'TotalF1:average=Macro',
            'verbose': 0,
            'classes_count': 3,
            'num_boost_round':500,
            'early_stopping_rounds': EARLY_STOPPING_ROUNDS
          }

# Datasets 
train_pool = Pool(train, y_train)
test_pool = Pool(test, y_test)
# Model Constructor
ctb_model = ctb.CatBoostClassifier(**params)
# Run feature selection
summary = ctb_model.select_features(
    train_pool,
    eval_set=test_pool,
    features_for_select='0-{0}'.format(train.shape[1]-1),
    num_features_to_select=10,
    steps=1,
    algorithm=EFeaturesSelectionAlgorithm.RecursiveByShapValues,
    shap_calc_type=EShapCalcType.Exact,
    train_final_model=True,
    logging_level='Silent',
    plot=True
)
```

After the run has ended, the following plot is displayed:

[image]

It is clear that according to the plot the evaluation metric is `TotalF1` with `macro` average, and the best iteration of the model achieved 0.6153 as the best score for this metric. According to the [documentation](https://catboost.ai/docs/concepts/python-reference_catboostclassifier_select_features.html), when the `train_final_model` argument is set to `True`, a model is finally fitted using the selected features that gave the best score for the specified evaluation metric during the feature selection process, so one would expect to get the same results when using the fitted model to make predictions and evaluate it. However, this is not the case.

When running:

```
from sklearn.metrics import f1_score
predictions = ctb_model.predict(test[summary['selected_features_names']], prediction_type='Class')
f1_score(y_test, predictions, average='macro')
```

The result i'm getting is:

```
0.41210319323424227
```

The difference is huge, and i can't figure out what is causing this difference.

How to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to this question can be found at: [CatBoost precision imbalanced classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54437646/catboost-precision-imbalanced-classes)

After setting the parameter `sample_weights` of the sklearn's `f1_score()`, i got the same F1 score than Catboost was throwing.